# explorer.exe fails at least once or twice and reloads

Tags: crash

I have a unusual problem, and i've tossed almost every diagnostic tool i can at this that I am fluent with, except debugging, i have no skills in this, id like to request some help to figure out why my explorer.exe crashes almost once a day, with no clear cause.

sfc /scannow , DISM Health Checks, CHKDSK, BSOD viewers.  nothing seems to tell me what this is, but I do have the Event viewer.

Faulting application name: Explorer.EXE, version: 10.0.22621.3296, time stamp: 0x48d2cb32
Faulting module name: Explorer.EXE, version: 10.0.22621.3296, time stamp: 0x48d2cb32
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x00000000000a2c30
Faulting process id: 0x0x26B4
Faulting application start time: 0x0x1DA7779F2502A71
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE
Report Id: daa0b267-9ad8-44b6-8921-da48aea2e3ad
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID: